# How to echo variable, where is "^&"? (Batch File)

Tags: batch-file, variables, echo

Is there any possibility to
set variable "Message1 & Message2" and echo that variable?

For example:

```
set var=Message1 ^& Message2
echo %var%
```

It shows that "Message2" is not a command.

(if you put "echo Message1 ^& Message2" it will shows "Message1 & Message2" normally.)

Comment: Use `set "var=Message1 ^& Message2"` in first line to define the message with `^` and `&`  assigned to `var`. Then the caret character is also on line `echo Message1 ^& Message2` on execution and `^` is interpreted as escape character for the ampersand. I recommend also reading answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add quotes like this

```
set "var=Message1 ^& Message2"
echo %var%
```

Answer (score 3):

you have various options:

```
@echo off
set var=Message1 ^^^& Message2
echo a %var%

set "var=Message1 ^& Message2"
echo b %var%

set "var=Message1 & Message2"
echo c %var:&=^&%
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the quoted syntax of the `set` command (which requires the command extensions to be enabled, but that is the default anyway) and use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), you do not even have to escape anything:

```cmd
set "var=Message1 & Message2"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!var!
endlocal
```